# android create system service

Tags: android, service, system

Do android have anything like system service? Windows have services, similar. I want to create a application similar to antivirus which should run as system service and other programs should not be able remove it not other programs should be able to modify/ delete its data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can create a system service, but you need to modify system image for this. If you can do this you can start it at the init.rc file or SystemServer.java. But for my point of view, Vinay is right - you should make an application with service. The application cannot be uninstalled by other applications, and the data of the application by default cannot be accessed by other applications (each application has its own user id. After that Android apply standard linux file permissions to the files of the applications).

Answer (score 1):

- You can create a service based app and install it.
- User will be able to install/uninstall as per his wish..
- This service can be started as soon as the phone is started with
  API's available.
- Each app has its own space/memory for it use and it cannot be accessed by other apps unless given permission.

Comment: i want to create system service.

Comment: I think, you will have to add it to the image of the OS as the OEMs do. I dont think it will be possible for a user to add it dynamically.